Where to locate the monthly Prayer Intentions of previous Popes?
The monthly prayer intentions of Pope Francis are found, for example, here.
QUESTION: Have the monthly prayer intentions of previous Popes been published somewhere, and if so, where may I find them? I am most interested in those of Ven. Pope Pius XII and his predecessors.

Started in 1844 as the Apostleship of Prayer it was only in 2016 when it was renamed1 It is also commonly referred to General Intention
You can use the waybackmachine to find previous year's prayer intentions, though this only goes back to 2019 which does not go back as far as you'd like.
Here the ones the site contains:

2023
2022
2021
2020
2019
...
1955

Dec


1918

Nov


1916

Oct


1908
1901
1900
1899
1896
1891
1884
1881

July - Dec


1876

Messenger of the Sacred Heart seems to have some. 1
OhioLINK references University of Dayton might have this as a hardcopy (reaching out, what they have is 1918 and 1916):

This collection consists of ephemera printed by the Apostleship of Prayer. The first two folders contain prayer cards arranged chronologically. Folder 3 contains brochures and letters published by the Apostleship, also arranged chronologically. Folder 4 contains badges distributed by the Apostleship, many of them decorated by their owners, and the next folder contains membership cards. The last folder contains various issues of the League Leaflet (later, the Monthly Leaflet), a monthly publication of the Apostleship.

1 https://www.aciprensa.com/noticias/62935/francisco-pide-a-fieles-unirse-a-la-red-mundial-de-oracion-del-papa and https://www.laciviltacattolica.it/articolo/la-rete-mondiale-di-preghiera-del-papa/ and https://www.popesprayer.va/history-of-the-apostleship-of-prayer/
I'll keep looking but have been unable to find any prayer intentions before those listed or digital version of either of the leaflets
1 Library of Congress: The Apostleship of Prayer, Ramière, Henri

+1 Many thanks for posting this.
